# Python - generate array of returns from function that changes its return value

Tags: python

What is a good pythonic way to generate an array of results from multiple function calls with a function that changes what it returns after each call?  For example, say I have a function `foo` that returns `'callno-X'` each time it is called, and X is increased by 1 every time.  I want to then be able to say something like `bar(5)` that will call `foo()` five times and gather the results in an array, returning `['callno-1','callno-2','callno-3','callno-4','callno-5']`.  Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: On your copious free time, take a look at [generators](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) and the `yield` statement; it is definitely related to the pattern you're observing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
returnValues = [foo() for x in xrange(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
map(foo, xrange(5))
```

It's short and simple.

Comment: Both map and list comprehension are basically doing the same thing.  My issue was trying to figure out how to get one of them to work with my example, which ended up being not that hard (I had temporarily forgotten about ranges).